# Permissive CORS check in meanjs.org application during development?

Tags: ionic-framework, cors, mean-stack, meanjs

I am using meanjs.org stack to develop a simple application. Now I am working on the mobile client with ionic framework.

Current issue I have is the CORS check causes an error when testing the ionic app like is described here: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/. While I could set up a proxy as described in that link it also works if I add the response header to the server side like: `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Adding this to each endpoint doesn't feels good and I would like to find a solution to use during development where I could disable the CORS check.

I've also tried changing the lusca configuration on config/env/default.js setting `xssProtection: false` bit didn't work?

How can I, during development, enable the following response header `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` in all endpoints, is it possible or the only viable solution using meanjs.org + Ionic during development is setting up the proxy?

Comment: If ur adding proxy, there is no need to set res.header to server side. It will work with proxy only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I finally got a hint on the meanjs.org forums and built a solution.

Create the following method on config/lib/express.js file:

```
/**
 * Disable CORS check to be used during development with access from mobile clients (currently tested with ionic)
 */
module.exports.disableCORSForDev = function(app) {
  app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  }).options('*', function(req, res) {
    res.end();
  });
  var corsOptionsDelegate = function(req, callback) {
    var corsOptions = { credentials: true };
    callback(null, corsOptions); // callback expects two parameters: error and options
  };
  app.use(cors(corsOptionsDelegate));
};
```

added the following to the method init on this same class just after declaration of var app = express();

```
var app = express();

this.disableCORSForDev(app);
```

> Note: This is a **server side solution** to bypass cors during development and should not be used in production, many may prefer to setup a proxy on the ionic client instead as it's described in this [**ionic article**](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/).

Answer (score 0):

For development you can set proxy to avoid CORS issues,

Set up your ionic.project file to be something like:

```
{
 "name": "proxy-example",
 "app_id": "",
 "proxies": [{
  "path": "/api",
  "proxyUrl": "http://example.com/api"
 }]
}
```

Then from controller call api like below,

```
.controller('MyController', function($http) {
     $http.post('/api/getMoreDeatils',data)
          .then(function (response) {
       //do something
     })
})
```

Hope this is helpful for you

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but as I mentioned in my question I was looking for a solution where this would be enabled or disabled by a flag on the server side API implementation. The proxy approach as described in the question we already know of. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a middleware like this in your server main file:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```